# Solving $\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{4-3x}}{x-1}\right)$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{4-3x}}{x-1}\right)$$

So

$$\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{4-3x}}{x-1} \cdot \frac{1+\sqrt[3]{4-3x}}{1+\sqrt[3]{4-3x}}$$

Then

$$\frac{1-(4-3x)}{(x-1)(1+\sqrt[3]{4-3x})}$$

That's

$$\frac{3\cdot \color{red}{(x-1)}}{\color{red}{(x-1)}(1+\sqrt[3]{4-3x})}$$

Finally

$$\frac{3}{(1+\sqrt[3]{4-3x})}$$

But this evaluates to

$$\frac{3}{2}$$

When the answer should be

$$1$$

Where did I fail?

Comment: You did not rationalize well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you used 
(a-b)(a+b) to simplify a cubic root instead of a simple root

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you may observe that, for any differentiable function $f$, you have

> $$
> \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \to f'(a).
> $$

Then use it with $a=1$ and
$$
f(x)=\sqrt[3]{4-3x},\quad \quad f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(4-3 x)^{2/3}}
$$ giving
$$
\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{4-3x}}{x-1}\right)=-f'(1)=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up square roots and cube roots:

$$(1-\sqrt[2]{a})*(1+\sqrt[2]{a})=1-a$$

$$(1-\sqrt[3]{a})*(1+\sqrt[3]{a})≠1-a$$

Comment: I recommend you split the denominator to $(x^1/3)^3-(1)^3, that might work. Or you can go start into LH rule.

Answer (score 1):

I think you overlooked this multiplication $(1+(4-3x)^{1/3})(1-(4-3x)^{1/3})$ which equals $1-(4-3x)^{2/3}$ not $1-(4-3x)$

Answer (score 1):

$ (1-(4-3x)^(1/3))(1+(4-3x)^(1/3)) = 1 - (4-3x)^(2/3) $

I couldn't re-format it right but others beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

If you let $t=4-3x,\;$ so $x=\frac{1}{3}(4-t)$,  you get

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{4-3x}}{x-1}=\lim_{t\to1}\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{t}}{\frac{1}{3}(1-t)}=\lim_{t\to1}\frac{3(1-t^{1/3})}{(1-t^{1/3})(1+t^{1/3}+t^{2/3})}=\lim_{t\to1}\frac{3}{1+t^{1/3}+t^{2/3}}=1$